# Input fields alignment in JSP/JSF

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsf

How can I align all the input fields in a JSF panelGrid? I have tried to use the code below to align the fields, but the first input field is not properly aligned.

Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="MF">
    <div align="center" class="form-align">
        <div align="left" class="block-align use-border" style="width:80%">
            <div align="left" class="block-align" style="width:100%">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" frame="none" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText id="lbl1" styleClass="lbltxt" value="#{---}" style="width:200px;"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" frame="none" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <h:column>
                                <h:inputText id="txt1" value="#{---}" styleClass="inputfld" size="10" maxlength="6" onfocus="gotFocusEvents(this)" onkeydown="keyDownEvents(this)" onkeypress="keyPressEvents(this)" onkeyup="keyUpEvents(this)"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputLabel id="outlbl1" for="txt1" styleClass="lbltxt"/>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:column>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>
        <div align="left" class="block-align use-border" style="width:80%">
            <div align="left" class="block-align" style="width:100%">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" frame="none" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">

                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText id="lbl2" value="#{---}" styleClass="lbltxt" style="width:200px;"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:inputText id="txt2" value="#{---}" styleClass="inputfld" size="10" readonly="true"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText style="text-align:left;" id="lbl3" styleClass="lbltxt" value="#{---}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:inputTextarea id="txt3" value="#{---}"
                                         styleClass="inputfld" rows="10" cols="65"
                                         onfocus="gotFocusEvents(this)" onkeydown="keyDownEvents(this)" onkeypress="keyPressEvents(this)">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText id="lbl4" value="#{---}" styleClass="lbltxt" style="width:200px;"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:inputTextarea id="txt4" value="#{---}"
                                         styleClass="inputfld" rows="10" cols="65"
                                         onfocus="gotFocusEvents(this)" onkeydown="keyDownEvents(this)" onkeypress="keyPressEvents(this)">
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                    </h:column>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

I have tried to clear the cache from the browser and re-run the server, but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your labels exeed the width of 200px in the lower table.

You should add another styleclass to all labels (h:outputText) defining the width and also the min-width. set the value as big as the widest label in your tables you want to align.

You should also avoid styling elements directly, if possible, to save yourself and others working on this code from unnessesary messy and inconsistent style.